# Как в express 4.x принять данные application/json?

Tags: node.js, http, express

Так я делаю запрос:

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'blabla/saveData/',
    type: 'POST',
    contentType: 'application/json',
    data: data,
    success: function(){
        alert('Save success');
    },
    error: function(data) {
        console.error(data);
    }
});
```

Так в роуте я пытаюсь принять запрос:

```
router.post("/blabla/saveData", function(req, res) ...
```

В итоге получаю 500 Internal Server Error. Как правильно распарсить такой запрос? В express что-нибудь есть для этого или нужно самому ловить запрос?

Answer (score 1):

https://github.com/expressjs/body-parser делает это

Пример

```
var express = require('express')
var bodyParser = require('body-parser')

var app = express()

// parse application/x-www-form-urlencoded
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }))

// parse application/json
app.use(bodyParser.json())

app.post('/blabla/saveData', function (req, res) {
    //req.body
    ...
})
```

Comment: У меня он используется, такие-же параметры, не работает

Answer (score 1):

```
 const express = require('express'),
       querystring = require('querystring'); 

  app.post('/blabla/saveData', function (req, res) {
     req.on('data', (chunk) => {
        let obj = querystring.parse(chunk.toString());//buffer в строку
            console.dir(obj.name);
        })
  })
```

Если вы используете ещё библиотеку require('request') - для запросов на другой сервер, то можно принимать ответ

```
  request.post({url: 'http://example.com/api'},(err, response, body)=>{
      let obj = JSON.parse(body);
  }
```

JSON.parse - если вы точно знаете что JSON, 
querystring.parse - просто строку парсит по определённым символам. настроить можно 2 символа.